# Generic with Bounds vs. Interface with Generic Types

Tags: java, generics

Consider the following code

```
/**
 * Generic method with bounds
 */
public static <T> int countGreaterThan(Comparable<T>[] anArray,
        T elem) {
    int count = 0;
    for (Comparable<T> e : anArray)
        if (e.compareTo(elem) > 0)
            ++count;
    return count;
}
/**
 * Alternative to above
 */
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> int countGreaterThan(T[] anArray, T elem) {
    int count = 0;
    for (T e : anArray)
        if (e.compareTo(elem) > 0)
            ++count;
    return count;
}
```

It appears that both are functionally the same. However they can appear in the same class apparently overloading each other. When I use the following code, it seems the second method gets invoked. Without the second overloading method, the first method get invoked. Can someone provide an in-depth explanation?

```
    Integer[] array = new Integer[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i)
        array[i] = i;

    System.out.println("Count > 5 = " + countGreaterThan(array, 5));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it's not a complete erasure.

The first method

```
<T> int countGreaterThan(Comparable<T>[] anArray,T elem)
```

works on an array of `Comparable<T>`, but does not mandate that `elem` is also `Comparable`.

You could check it on:

```
static class Y {
   int val;
   public Y(int val){
      this.val=val;
   }
} 

static class W extends Y implements Comparable<Y>{
   public W(int val){
      super(val);
   }
   public int compareTo(Y o){
      return this.val-o.val;
   } 
}

W[] array = new W[10];
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; ++i)
    array[i] = new W(i);

System.out.println("Count > 5 = " + countGreaterThan(array, new Y(5)));
```

The first method will be called.

Comment: Yes but his question is why the second one is called. By this argument the first should be called right? but #2 is.

Comment: @SeanOwen The second is called when `param` is also `Comparable<T>`, as for why it happens, it is easily explained: the matching rule for the late binding method signatures prediliges the more restrictive ones, so when you use Integer as T which is also Comparable<T>, the second method is called.

Comment: @SeanOwen also remember that generics are erased by the compiler, so the methods are matched as: `countGreaterThan(Comparable[] anArray, Object elem)` and `countGreaterThan(Comparable[] anArray, Comparable elem)`

Comment: @SeanOwen no, it erases to   `// Method descriptor #51 ([Ljava/lang/Comparable;Ljava/lang/Comparable;)I
  // Signature: <T::Ljava/lang/Comparable<TT;>;>([TT;TT;)I
  // Stack: 2, Locals: 7
  public static int countGreaterThan(java.lang.Comparable[] anArray, java.lang.Comparable elem);` as per classFile inspection

Comment: Sorry you are correct, I forgot that the second has a type bound!

Answer (score 1):

(They can appear in the same class since they don't have the same erasure. The first one has a first argument of type `Comparable[]` and the second of type `Object[]`.)

Both methods could apply; in Java, the method to call is determined at compile time and is always the more-specific overloading based on the argument's reference type.

Carlo Pellegrini makes a good point that the first would be called for any old `Comparable`. Greater experts may correct me, but I am fairly sure this is due to boxing. The call in your example binds `Integer[]` to `T[]` first, and then this induces the boxing of `int` to `T` which is now reified as `Integer`. In the case of his example `Y`, it can only match the first one.

Answer (score 0):

That's because in Java, an `Integer[]` is also a `Comparable[]`. If you had the same method with a list instead of an array as arguments, it wouldn't work the same way, because a `List<Integer>` is not a `List<Comparable>`. So only the second version would accept a `List<Integer>` as argument.

Collections are more type-safe and work better with generics than arrays. You should prefer them over arrays in general.

Comment: But isn't this an argument that the first method is called? the second one is called in fact.

Comment: It's an argument that both methods are compatible wit the arguments you pass. But since the second one is more specific (because Integer is more specific than Comparable) that one is called. Just like if you had `foo(Object)` and `foo(Integer)` and called foo with an Integer, the second one would be called.

Comment: This wouldn't explain why `Y` in Carlo's example behaves differently, because `Y` is also more specific than `Comparable`. Boxing -- I believe -- is the difference.

Comment: My answer explains why, in the OP's example, both methods apply, and why, in the OP's example, the first one would not apply if a List<Integer> was used. My first comment explains why the second method in the OP's example is chosen by the compiler instead of the first one. If you take another example, sure, the same rules don't necessarily apply. And frankly, I can't explain why in Carlo's example one is chosen over the other. I would have to dive into the JLS for that.